# Checking Dynamically generated Checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am dynamically generating the checkboxes as follows:

```
entries.each(function()
{
    if($(this).find('parentcategoryid').text() == 0)                
    {
        xmlArr += '<span><input type="checkbox" data-mini="true" name="category'+$(this).find('categoryid').text()+'" id="checkbox'+$(this).find('categoryid').text()+'" class="techAreasCheckBox" style="margin-top: 5px;"/><label class="techAreasLabel">'+$(this).find('categoryname').text()+'</label></span><br>'; 
    } 
    else
    {
        xmlArr;
    }                   
}); // Entries.Each function
```

say the names of the checkboxes generated are as follows: category1, category2, category3, category8, category10, category54, category55, category56, category, 59, category62, category132, category133.

Also, I have an array of 4 numbers: 2, 54, 8, 10....

I want to check the checkboxes having name attribute ending with these numbers in array. How shall I proceed?

Note: These are DYNAMICALLY GENERATED Checkboxes.

Comment: Please format your code. it hurt my eyes and head too:|

Comment: check this : http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check the checkboxes, all you need to do is add the checked attribute as described [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp).

Below is one solution.  First, you want to store the Id instead of looking it up every time because it's faster.  Second, I used the $.inArray function to determine if the category is in the array that contains the numbers that should be checked.  Finally, I used a ternary to add the checked attribute.

```
var numberArray = [2, 54, 8, 10];

entries.each(function() {
     if($(this).find('parentcategoryid').text() == 0) {
          var categoryId = $(this).find('categoryid').text();
          var categoryInArray = $.inArray(categoryId, numberArray) !== -1;

          xmlArr += '<span><input type="checkbox" data-mini="true" name="category'+categoryId+'" id="checkbox'+categoryId+'" class="techAreasCheckBox" style="margin-top: 5px;"' + categoryInArray ? ' checked="checked" ' : '""/><label class="techAreasLabel">'+$(this).find('categoryname').text()+'</label></span><br/>'; 
     }
}); // Entries.Each function
```

Alternatively you can just use another if statement.

```
entries.each(function() {
     if($(this).find('parentcategoryid').text() == 0) {
          var categoryId = $(this).find('categoryid').text();
          var categoryInArray = $.inArray(categoryId, numberArray) !== -1;

          if(categoryInArray) {
          xmlArr += '<span><input type="checkbox" data-mini="true" name="category'+categoryId+'" id="checkbox'+categoryId+'" class="techAreasCheckBox" style="margin-top: 5px;" checked="checked"/><label class="techAreasLabel">'+$(this).find('categoryname').text()+'</label></span><br/>'; 
          } else {
          xmlArr += '<span><input type="checkbox" data-mini="true" name="category'+categoryId+'" id="checkbox'+categoryId+'" class="techAreasCheckBox" style="margin-top: 5px;"/><label class="techAreasLabel">'+$(this).find('categoryname').text()+'</label></span><br/>'; 
          }
     }
}); // Entries.Each function
```

Comment: This one worked perfectly :) I used your technique and had some tweaks :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`jQuery.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to iterate through your array of numbers, then select the element with an `id` equal to `category-X` (where `X` is the current number):

```
$.each(numbers, function(i, num) {
    $('#category-' + num).prop('checked', true);
});
```

Alternatively, if you only want to do this when *creating* the elements, you could simply add the `checked` attribute to the HTML when appropriate.